# mainframe practice on Mac machine

Tags: db2, cobol, mainframe, jcl

Is there a way to use mainframe on Mac machine. I want to practice mainframes(COBOL, JCL, DB2) on MAC or windows, preferably MAC.

Comment: @Wooble I have worked as mainframe developer for many years for IBM. But for last 3 years I am not, hence need to practice. Just wanted to know is there a simulator, i know there is one, but its not good enough.

Comment: The best you probably can do is find a COBOL compiler for Mac.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have never tried, but [Hercules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hercules_%28emulator%29) is a mainframe emulator that should run on OSX. The main problem though with any kind of mainframe emulation is getting the software you want. Very few (if any) of the software that runs on modern mainframe is licensed to run on emulators.

If you provide a bit more background as to what you are trying to achieve, then someone should be able to come up with a more helpful answer. That is, are you trying to understand the architecture, learn assembler, work with IMS or CICS, etc?

Comment: Hercules runs very nicely on OSX.

Comment: Seconded, but you should feel comfortable when in *N*X command prompts and building software from scratch. If you are just familiar with working with a Mac through the user interface, there will be an additional learning curve.

Comment: Hercules itself may run fine but you won't be able to legally run any "z/OS" later than MVS 3.8j, which is to z/OS as CP/M is to Linux :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using Topaz on AWS by Compuware (https://compuware.com/topaz-on-aws/). The mainframe IDE runs in a browser so it doesn't matter what operating system you use. Plus, it works great and has tons of useful, modern features. But if you need a free emulator, you can use tn3270x (https://www.brown.edu/cis/tn3270/).

Answer (score 0):

You should look for a service that let's you connect to a minframe from the internet with a 3270 emulator that would run on your PC or Mac.  Maybe some colleges would offer that.

Answer (score 0):

You can register for Master the Mainframe contest organized by IBM, to get free access to genuine IBM Mainframes. 
Click [here](https://www.ibm.com/it-infrastructure/z/education/master-the-mainframe) and Register for Learning System.

Read these lines in link's description.

> Master the Mainframe is a fun way to learn, earn digital badges and
>   experience hands-on mainframe technology with no prior knowledge
>   required!
>
> Master the Mainframe’s Learning System is open to anyone year-round
>   for technology training and earning IBM digital badges.
>
> Yearly, the IBM Z Academic Initiative sponsors a Master the Mainframe
>   global contest where academic students can learn while vying to win
>   prizes. New challenges are posted each September.

I've been using Vista TN3270 terminal on my PC for a month and it's quite interesting and useful.